# DependencyObject with no dependency on WPF?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Is there any library or NuGet package with DependencyObject analog? I'm looking for hierarchical properties implementation, but do not want a dependency on WPF assemblies. Target platform — .NET Core.

Comment: Asking for a library recommendation is out of scope for stackoverflow. Maybe you can elaborate more on your actual problem / task? It's not really clear to me what you try to achieve

Comment: Did you find a solution, Dennis? I want to use DependencyObject and DependencyProperty in a .Net Core application, so I can also not use WPF assemblies.

I know that DependencyObject and DependencyProperty originated in UI related work, but I find the general concept so powerful that I use it all the time.

Comment: @Paul ten Brink, no I did not. I did not need the whole DO implementation, so I made a simple one by my self. Something like this: https://pastebin.com/eEpuGb43